# Как группировать итоги в JasperReports?

Tags: jasperreports

Делаю отчет в jasperReports и требуется группировка итогов в конце определенного периода. Получается идет сначала секция Detail после неё следуют сгруппированные итоги по секции.
[image: То как у меня получается]
На данный момент каждый итог выводится под своей частью секции. [image: Требуется такой вид]